# Ошибка импорта модуля Bio

Tags: python, python-3.x, biopython

Пытался импортировать библиотеку ProDy.
Использовал и то, что описано в документации: `from prody import *`, и `import prody`. Однако получал ошибку: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'`

Все эти библиотеки у меня есть:

[image: Список установленных модулей]

Перед импортом ProDy даже писал `import bio`, что не изменило проблему.

Как ни странно, если ввести просто `import bio` без дальнейшего импорта ProDy, я не получаю ошибки об отсутствии модуля Bio!

Я пытался переустанавливать эти библиотеки, но проблема не решилась.

Библиотекой ProDy мало кто пользуеться, так что даже поиск на английском в гугле не выдал нужных результатов.

Очень надеюсь, что кто-то сталкивался с подобным

Дополненно:

```py
from bio.PDB import *
```

тоже выдаёт ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'`

Comment: Как вы устанавливали модуль `ProDy`?

Comment: @MaxU `pip3 install prody`, `pip install prody`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошло три месяца, но да, похоже вопрос как-то решился тогда и я о нём позабыл. До этого момента. Ведь я переустановил питон и весь `pip list` тоже. В итоге столкнулся с подобной проблемой...

Итак, помогла лишь переустановка, тоесть:

```
pip uninstall biopython
pip install biopython
```

Если кто-то столкнулся с этой проблемой, то вот, что помогло мне. Без понятия, что это за танцы с бубном, но надеюсь, что вам это тоже поможет)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать виртуальное окружение, используя `conda`:

запустите `Anaconda Prompt`. Все последующие команды запускаются из `Anaconda Prompt`.

```
conda create -n bio python=3.6 chardet cycler numpy scipy pandas matplotlib ipython biopython -y
conda activate bio
pip install -U ProDy
```

Проверка:

```
In [1]: import prody

In [2]: prody.__version__
Out[2]: '1.10.10'

In [3]: prody.sequence.
 alignSequencesByChain()          buildPCMatrix()                  MSA                              showDirectInfoMatrix()
 alignSequenceToMSA()             buildSCAMatrix()                 msa                              showMSAOccupancy()
 alignTwoSequencesWithBiopython() buildSeqidMatrix()               MSAFile                          showMutinfoMatrix()
 analysis                         calcMeff()                       msafile                          showSCAMatrix()
 applyMutinfoCorr()               calcMSAOccupancy()               parseMSA()                       showShannonEntropy()
 applyMutinfoNorm()               calcPercentIdentities()          plotting                         specMergeMSA()
 buildDirectInfoMatrix()          calcRankorder()                  refineMSA()                      splitSeqLabel()
 buildMSA()                       calcShannonEntropy()             Sequence                         uniqueSequences()
 buildMutinfoMatrix()             filterRankedPairs()              sequence                         writeMSA()
 buildOMESMatrix()                mergeMSA()                       showAlignment()

In [4]: import Bio

In [5]: Bio.__version__
Out[5]: '1.73'

In [6]: from Bio.PDB import
                      AbstractPropertyMap  CaPPBuilder          Entity               FragmentMapper       HSExposureCB         make_dssp_dict
                      Atom                 Chain                ExposureCN           get_surface          is_aa                MMCIF2Dict
                      calc_angle           Dice                 extract              HSExposure           kdtrees              mmcifio              >
                      calc_dihedral        DSSP                 FastMMCIFParser      HSExposureCA         m2rotaxis            MMCIFIO
```